# Sony Spresenseとデジタルマイクで音を収集

Tags: spresense

Sony Spresenseとデジタルマイク（型番：IM69D130）で
音声ファイルをSDカードに保存したいと考えています。
デジタルマイクを使ったサンプルプログラムを
どなたかおもちではないでしょうか？
そのサンプルプログラムを参考にして開発をしたいと
思います。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「自分はここまでやったけど、この部分がわからないので教えてください」とか「こういうことをやりたいけど、どこから始めれば良いですか」といった質問の仕方にしたほうが回答が付きやすいと思います。「あったらください」ではいかにも直球的過ぎるのでは…

Comment: すみません．それでは，質問を変えさせていただきます．「Sony Spresenseとデジタルマイク（型番：IM69D130）で音声ファイルをSDカードに保存したいと考えています。」どこから始めればよろしいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

Arduinoで開発されている場合は、Spresense用のスケッチ例の
Audio/application/recorder のサンプルスケッチの

```
theAudio->setRecorderMode(AS_SETRECDR_STS_INPUTDEVICE_MIC);
```

を変えることでデジタルにできます。

```
err_t setRecorderMode(
      uint8_t input_device,
      int32_t input_gain,
      bool is_digital
  );
```

なので、

```
theAudio->setRecorderMode(AS_SETRECDR_STS_INPUTDEVICE_MIC, 0, 0x4000, true);
```

などに変更することでデジタルマイクでの録音ができます。

ただ、Gainがデジタルの場合0以上に設定できないのでかなり音が小さく、ソフトウェアでGain Upをする必要がありそうです。

以下のページが参考になりました。

[MP3 形式で録音する | Spresense Arduino サンプル＆チュートリアル](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_tutorials_ja.html#_mp3_%E5%BD%A2%E5%BC%8F%E3%81%A7%E9%8C%B2%E9%9F%B3%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)

Comment: ありがとうございます．Arduinoで開発していますので，このサンプルスケッチを参考に調べて見たいと思います．

Answer (score 0):

IM69D130はPDM(Pulse Density Modulation)出力なので、Spresense側からクロックを送ってやって、それに合わせてデータを読み込めば、データは取得できます。PDMですから、出てくるデータは０か１のいずれかです。

PDMのデータは、デジタル信号処理をしてデジタル音声信号に変換するか、そのまま出力してローパスフィルターによってアナログ音声信号に変換するかする必要があります。

[Arduinoのライブラリリスト](https://www.arduinolibraries.info/libraries)に、
「Adafruit Zero PDM Library
PDM Microphone Input library for Arduino Zero / Adafruit Feather M0 (SAMD21 processor).」 というのがあります。

使えるかもしれませんから、調べてみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます．PDMという出力なのですね．デジタルマイクは初めてなので，勉強になります．「Adafruit Zero PDM Library」の中にexampleのコードがありましたので，参考にしてみ見たいと思います．